# Optimize code to use an alternative for countDistinct / approx_count_distinct

Tags: scala, apache-spark, optimization, apache-spark-sql

The dataframe (`df`) that I am currently working with has 10 million rows. It looks like this

```
col1 col2
a     p1        
a     p1        
a     p2        
a     p2       
a     p3        
a     p3        
b     p1        
b     p3        
b     p3        
b     p2         
b     p2        
b     p2
```

I need to count the distinct number of values in `col2`, for every value in `col1`.

So, my expected output is

```
col4   col5  col6
a      p1    2
a      p2    2
a      p3    2
b      p1    1
b      p2    3
b      p3    2
```

I have tried using `countDistinct` and `approx_count_distinct`, but it takes hours to run the code (>10 hours), which is quite frustrating!

I have tried the following codes

Code1

```
df2 = df
    .groupBy($"col1", $"col2")
    .agg(approx_count_distinct($"col2"))
```

Code2 (takes more time than code1)

```
df2 = df
    .groupBy($"col1", $"col2")
    .agg(countDistinct($"col2"))
```

Is there any better way of counting distinct values that would reduce my code runtime? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you code does not compile (at least with Spark 2.3.1).

> I need to count the distinct number of values in col2, for every value
>   in col1.

To do this you should do

```
val df2 = df
.groupBy($"col1")
.agg(countDistinct($"col2"))
```

Are you sure that this part of the code takes that long? You can try to run `df.rdd.count` to see if your bottleneck is already in `df`

Comment: Missed agg, was a typo. Thanks for pointing it out. How is df.rdd.count different to df.count?

Answer (score -1):

What is col3?

All you need is count I would think

```
df2 = df.groupBy($"col1",$"col2").count
```

And a lot of executors possibly

Here is the example from the data you posted

```
scala> val df = Seq(
     | ("a", "p1"),
     | ("a", "p1"),
     | ("a", "p2"),
     | ("a", "p2"),
     | ("a", "p3"),
     | ("a", "p3"),
     | ("b", "p1"),
     | ("b", "p3"),
     | ("b", "p3"),
     | ("b", "p2"),
     | ("b", "p2"),
     | ("b", "p2")).toDF("col1", "col2")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: string]

scala> val df2 = df.groupBy($"col1",$"col2").count
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: string, count: bigint]

scala> df2.show
+----+----+-----+
|col1|col2|count|
+----+----+-----+
|   a|  p1|    2|
|   a|  p2|    2|
|   a|  p3|    2|
|   b|  p1|    1|
|   b|  p2|    3|
|   b|  p3|    2|
+----+----+-----+
```

Comment: Edited col3 to be col2, was a typo! Any other ideas? i have already tried this, is slow

Comment: Where is your data coming from and what is the size of your cluster? My guess is the slow down is coming from the shuffle partitioning, First thing to try would be to set the spark.sql.shuffle.partitions to a high value say 2000 then write the data out to parquet partitioned by col2, read the parquet file back in and run my suggestion from above. Also tune the cluster resources as needed.